# Quadtree graphic display in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, quadtree

I'm writing a class in Java (Eclipse) which implements a quadtree structure. For those of you who are not familiar with this structure, it is simply a square that gets divided recursively into four other squares as shown in the figure below.
[image: QuadTree]

I want to display the data structure as shown below. Does anyone have a nice idea for a simple implementation ?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's AWT or Swing to create a window and draw the quad tree in there. For example, in Swing you could create a `JPanel` and do the drawing there. It does not need to be very complicated as it's only a matter of drawing lines and possibly squares.

Comment: thank you, but i want that the code will do it automatically while it divide the square, because sometime it can be only 1 divide while another time be 4 divided.....  how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [ACM Java Task Force](http://jtf.acm.org/) has a nice and very simple graphics package to do this kind of stuff.

You can find a good tutorial [here](http://jtf.acm.org/rationale/graphics-package.html).